# actualizar un div cada cierto tiempo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, div

por favor necesito ayuda con lo siguiente necesito actualizar un div que contiene una tabla cada cierto tiempo y estoy usando el siguiente codigo

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#act1").load("../views/vistaLotes.php")
            .error(function() { alert("Error"); });
        }, 1000);

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });              
    });
</script>
```

y veo que lo hace pero en vez de actualizar el div lo que hace es sobre escribir
literal lo pone encima [image: este es el resultado]

agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Y has intentado vaciar el contenido del div antes de que se termine el load?

Comment: si lo intente con un empy() pero no me funciono o se hace de otra forma? muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Un arreglo rápido seria éste, debería funcionar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#act1").empty();
            $("#act1").load("../views/vistaLotes.php")
            .error(function() { alert("Error"); });
        }, 1000);

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });              
    });
</script>
```

ya me estoy yendo pero cuando llego te doy una respuesta mas apropiada si nadie mas lo hace.

Comment: lo voy a probar... gracias

Comment: lo acabo de probar y no se soluciona el problema

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es vaciar el contenido del `<div>` de la siguiente forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#act1").html('');
            $("#act1").load("../views/vistaLotes.php")
            .error(function() { alert("Error"); });
        }, 1000);

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });              
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes limpiar el div antes de pintar los nuevos datos, por lo que necesitas agregar una llamada a la función **empty** y luego cargar el nuevo contenido.
algo así:

```
$('#act1').empty().load("../views/vistaLotes.php")
```